# Kubuntu 22.04 Live USB fails, reports "Out of Memory" with no details, even after working on other machines

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I have a [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) USB, with [Boot Repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and Kubuntu 22.04.

Earlier today, on a different machine, I installed Kubuntu 22.04 from this USB normally, and that worked fine, so I am confident it's not the live USB. On the machine with the "Out of Memory" problem for Kubuntu 22.04, I **can** load the Boot Repair ISO, and it doesn't report any issues. The machine I'm trying to load the ISO onto is a Lenovo Yoga 730-15IKB with dual-booted Kubuntu 21.04 (which I am trying to update, as `sudo do-release-upgrade` is not working) and Windows.

However, when I load the Kubuntu 22.04 ISO from the live USB, the following happens:

The standard text appears:

```
Try or install Kubuntu
Kubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
```

I select `Try or install Kubuntu`. It then goes to a black screen with the following text:

```
error: out of memory.

Press any key to continue...
```

There is no other error information or details. After a few seconds, or upon pressing a key, it goes to the manufacturer logo splash screen and freezes until I manually power down and restart.

I couldn't find any others with this error that didn't also have a lot of other, more detailed, error output, but the "out of memory" error is fairly generic, so I may have missed something.

Comment: Please be precise with details; there is no Kubuntu 21, and Ubuntu products using the *year* format are different systems to those using the *year.month* format; you cannot upgrade a 20 product to 22.04; only 20.04 or 21.10 to 22.04.

Comment: Fixed - I have Ubuntu 21.04. I don't need to upgrade, necessarily - a reinstall would be fine, as I've made an external backup of all the things I need.

I may have Ubuntu 21.04 with the KDE desktop environment, rather than a Kubuntu. However, I don't think what I currently have installed should affect the ability of the ISO to load from the live USB.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I'm attempting to upgrade to (K)Ubuntu 22.04 - I only gave my installation specifications since they may be relevant, but the real problem is that I can't boot the Ubuntu 22.04 live USB, despite confirming that (1) the live USB works, and is able to install on other machines and (2) other ISOs on the live USB work on the machine with the issue.

Frankly, I could nuke the entire 21.04 partition, but I'm doubtful that it would help - I wouldn't expect the existing install to affect one from another installation medium that begins booting and errors out when I try to "try or install".

Comment: I had the same issue with an Ubuntu 22.04 ISO image burnt on an USB drive from Ubuntu 21.04. I re-did the USB on Windows by using Rufus and now everything works.

Comment: You can upgrade 21.04 to 21.10 and then to 22.04 LTS. 8 GB of memory should be sufficient to run 22.04 from RAM. So the question remains how much space do you have on the partition?

Comment: Since you can easily drag and drop iso's on your usb stick ( using Ventoy ) why don't you try 20.04 LTS if it has the same problem or not. ( 20.04 you can upgrade to 22.04!)

Answer (score 0):

If grub is your bootloader we can try another thing. You need ( as commented earlier ) enough space on the partition where you want to install Kubuntu to.
Place the Kubuntu 22.04.iso on your Windows partition.
Edit your current grub.cfg ( make backup first and name it e.g. grubold.cfg ). Add the folowing:

```
menuentry "Kubuntu" {
insmod ext2
set isofile="/@/kubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
loopback loop (hd0,7)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject quiet splash toram
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

Change 'kubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso' with the exact name of the .iso
Change 'hd0,7' with the harddisk and partitionnumber where your .iso is ( probably hd0,3, when you have the EFI partition, a small Windows partition (for bitlocker) and then your main Windows partition ). See my pictures.[image][image]. In my case my iso is located on harddisk 0,partition 7(in my Kubuntu partition). My # custom is 42, in your case it probably will be 40. 
Now you made your iso in the root of your Windows partition bootable. Boot it and try to install it this way. Let me know what happens.